# R: merge text documents by index

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
_________________id ________________text______
    1   | 7821             | "some text here"
    2   | 7821             |  "here as well"
    3   | 7821             |  "and here"
    4   | 567              |   "etcetera"
    5   | 567              |    "more text"
    6   | 231              |   "other text"
```

And I would like to group the texts by IDs, so I can run a clustering algorithm:

```
________________id___________________text______
    1   | 7821             | "some text here here as well and here"
    2   | 567              |   "etcetera more text"
    3   | 231              |   "other text"
```

Is there any way to do this? I am importing from a database table and I have a lot of data, so I can't do it manually.

Comment: @Arun, Totally agree, but here's a trick for when you run across such tables: copy and paste everything but the first line, and use `read.table` with `sep = "|"` and `strip.white = TRUE`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're actually looking for `aggregate`, not `merge`, and there should be *many* examples on SO demonstrating different options for aggregation. Here's the most basic and direct approach, using the formula approach to specify which columns to `aggregate`.

Here's your data in a copy-and-pasteable form

```
mydata <- structure(list(id = c(7821L, 7821L, 7821L, 567L, 567L, 231L), 
    text = structure(c(6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("and here", 
    "etcetera", "here as well", "more text", "other text", "some text here"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "text"), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Here's the aggregated output.

```
aggregate(text ~ id, mydata, paste, collapse = " ")
#     id                                 text
# 1  231                           other text
# 2  567                   etcetera more text
# 3 7821 some text here here as well and here
```

Of course, there is also `data.table`, which has nice compact syntax (and awesome speed):

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(mydata)
> DT[, paste(text, collapse = " "), by = "id"]
     id                                   V1
1: 7821 some text here here as well and here
2:  567                   etcetera more text
3:  231                           other text
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! I will accept your answer as soon as I can (in 4 minutes)!